# Incorrect param submitting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form for casting your vote for your favourite image.

```
<%= form_for(@imagevote) do |f| %>
      <% @miniature.collections(:photo).each do |collection| %>

        <% if collection.photo.exists? %>
          <td><div class="photo1">

         <%= link_to image_tag(collection.photo.url(:thumb), :retina => true), collection.photo.url(:original), :retina => true, :class => "image-popup-no-margins" %>
    <%= f.radio_button(:collection_id, collection.id) %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :voter_id, :value => current_user.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :voted_id, :value => collection.user_id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :miniature_id, :value => @miniature.id %>

         <p>Painted by <%= link_to collection.user.name, collection.user %></p>
             </div></td>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.submit "Vote" %>
    <% end %>
```

Everything submits correctly except for the `hidden_field :voted_id` which for some reason duplicates the `current_user.id`.

**UPDATE**

I've tried logging in as another user and it seems that `:voted_id` is not duplicating `current_user.id` but rather that it is always "7" which was the :user_id I was using to test it before. Now logged in as user number 4 it is still entering the `:voted_id` as 7. I'm lost.

The link to the imagevotes view is as follows:

```
<%= link_to "See more and change your vote.", edit_imagevote_path(:miniature_id => @miniature, :voter_id => current_user.id) %>
```

Here is my image votes controller

```
class ImagevotesController < ApplicationController

    respond_to :html, :js

    def new
        @imagevote = Imagevote.new
        @miniature = Miniature.find(params[:miniature_id])
    end

    def edit
        @imagevote = Imagevote.find_by_miniature_id_and_voter_id(params[:miniature_id],params[:voter_id]) 
        @miniature = Miniature.find(params[:miniature_id]) 
    end

    def create
        @imagevote = Imagevote.new(imagevote_params)
        if @imagevote.save
            flash[:success] = "Vote registered"
            redirect_to :back
        else
            flash[:success] = "Vote not registered"
            redirect_to :back
        end
    end

    def update
        @imagevote = Imagevote.find(params[:id])
        if @imagevote.update_attributes(imagevote_params)
            flash[:success] = "Vote changed."
            redirect_to :back
        else
            redirect_to :back
        end
    end

    private

    def imagevote_params
      params.require(:imagevote).permit(:collection_id, :voter_id, :voted_id, :miniature_id)
    end
end
```

Comment: Did you inspect the collection to make sure the collection.user_id isn't the same as the current_user.id?

Comment: Yes, regardless of the collection.user_id it always submits the current_user.id. I've tried it on numerous collections.

Comment: Does the current_user.id still appear if you swap out `collection.user_id` with a test value? For example just setting the value to "hi" instead of the `collection.user_id`

Comment: No, the test value appeared.

Comment: It looks like somewhere along the line collection.user_id is being set to the current user.

Comment: I've now included the link that takes you to the edit page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one `@imagevote` object, but you are outputting the hidden fields inside your collection loop so you will have multiple fields in the form referencing the same attribute on the model: if you check the html that is generated, you should see multiple hidden fields with the same `name` attribute.

The way that browsers handle multiple inputs with the same name means that the param that comes through for `:voted_id` will always be the `:user_id` from the last collection.

Comment: Aha! I can move the :voter_id and :miniature_id hidden fields out of the collection loop but how can I pass the :voted_id of the selected image? Can the radio button hold two params?

Comment: I can't find any way to get the radio button to pass both parameters but maybe there is a way to have a hidden field, after of the loop which takes it's :voted_id from the collection selected by the radio button?

Comment: Thanks for your help and don't worry I'll ask this in another question.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say because you didn't provide your model and your loop code stripped.

I would guess that you loop over `collection` that belongs to the `current_user`. And in this case you will have `current_user.id` always be the same as `collection.user_id`. May be you wanted to see `collection.photo_id`?

Comment: Oh sorry, for some reason the top of my code snippet wasn't showing. I've edited it to show that your guess is not the case.

Comment: What `collection.user.id` returns in this case?

Comment: If I put `<%= collection.user.id %>` in the loop then it displays the correct `user_id` but if I put it in the `hidden_field` it behaves just the same and returns the `current_user.id`.